# Array.push() inside Model.findOne() in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

I declare `ids` array and push the `id` in it.

I use Node.js and mongoose

**This is my code**

```
let ids = []
for (let i = 0; i < chatLen; i++) {
    let id = chats[i].sender_id == reqUserid ? chats[i].receiver_id : chats[i].sender_i
    if (ids.indexOf(id) == -1) {
        User.findOne({
            _id: new ObjectId(id)
        }).then(data => {
            if (data && data._id) {
                console.log(data);
                ids.push(data._id)
                socket.emit('GetChatter', data)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

How can I push id into the ids array?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: how can i push id into the ids array

Comment: this should work the way you did. Note that `User.findOne()` is `async` and the for loop will run into the next iteration before the user was loaded. But in the end the ID should be pushed anyway...

Comment: but this also means that `if (ids.indexOf(id) == -1) {` will not work as expected because of the async execution

Comment: What I change in my code to achieve `if (ids.indexOf(id) == -1) {`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working because `User.findOne()` is `async` function.

**Try this code.**

```
let chatLen = chats.length;
GetUserFromChat(chatLen)
async function GetUserFromChat(chatLen) {
    let ids = []
    for (let i = 0; i < chatLen; i++) {
        let id = chats[i].sender_id == reqUserid ? chats[i].receiver_id : chats[i].sender_id;
        console.log(ids);

        if (ids.indexOf(id) == -1) {
            await User.findOne({
                _id: new ObjectId(id)
            }).then(data => {
                if (data && data._id) {
                    socket.emit('GetChatter', data)
                    ids.push(data._id)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**

if you want performance use this.

```
(async () => {
let FriendLen = req.user.friends.length;
const promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < FriendLen; i++) {
    const acc = Events.findOne({ host_id : req.user.friends[i] });
    promises.push(acc)
}
const events = await Promise.all(promises);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is evaluated `async` and that's why your script is not working as expected. If you want to execute the iteration `synchronously` you could make use of `async / await`:

```
function waitForUserIdAndEmitData(id) {
    return User.findOne({
        _id: new ObjectId(id)
    }).then(data => {
        if (data && data._id) {
            socket.emit('GetChatter', data)
            return data._id
        }
    })
}

async function iterate(chatLen) {   // <- note "async"

  let ids = []

   for (let i = 0; i < chatLen; i++) {
     let id = chats[i].sender_id == reqUserid ? chats[i].receiver_id : chats[i].sender_i
     if (ids.indexOf(id) == -1) {
       const userId = await waitForUserId(id) // <- note "await"
       ids.push(userId)
     }
   }
   console.log(ids)
}

iterate(chatLen)
```